# How to get BBox width & height of a group of Raphael objects?

Tags: javascript, raphael, javascript-framework

In Raphel.js, how to get BBox width & height of a group of Raphael objects ?

For example, I have rendered several elements on my Rapheal paper as below:

```
var paper = Raphael(10, 50, 320, 200);
var st = paper.set();

var c = paper.rect(40, 40, 50, 50, 10);
var e = paper.ellipse(50, 50, 40, 20);
var i = paper.image("apple.png", 10, 10, 80, 80);
var t = paper.text(50, 50, "Raphaël\nkicks\nbutt!");
...

st.push(c, e, i, t ...);
```

I tried to use the following way to get BBox width and height of a group of elements:

```
var myBBox = st.getBBox();
var width = myBBox.width;
var height = myBBox.height;

console.log(width+','+height);
```

Sometimes it is working, but sometimes I got value ***Infinity*** for height. I guess it is a bug of Rapheal. So, If I want to get the current BBox size of my canvas (a group of elements), what is the correct way to do it?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I think this may have been fixed in 2.0

Answer (score 1):

You can do it manually. For each element of group:

1. Get `left` or `x` coordinate. Get the minimal value. `var MinLeft`
2. Get `right` coordinate. It can be calculated like `left`+`width` or `x2`. Get the maximum value. `var MaxRight`
3. Get `top` or `y` coordinate. Get the minimal value. `var MinTop`
4. Get `bottom` coordinate. It can be calculated like `top`+`height` or `y2`. Get the maximum value. `var MaxBottom`
5. Result: your group's `left`=`MinLeft`; your group's `top`=`MinTop`; your group's `height`=`MaxBottom-MinTop`; your group's `width`=`MaxRight-MinLeft`